# Varying amount of Arguments in Pydbus

Tags: python-3.x, interface, dbus, gdbus

I now set up a Pydbus server and exported some methods, but one method keeps me guessing. The amount of arguments used in this method is changing. In Python this is simply done with MyMethod(*arg, **kwarg). If I write this function into my XML interface I have to define the exact amount of arguments.

Is there any way to not specify the exact amount of arguments? So that I could in theory use one argument on the first usage and unlimited arguments the second time?

Thanks for your help,
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier to answer this question concretely if you provided code examples (from the introspection XML) to illustrate the problem.

I’m going to guess that you want `MyMethod` to be polymorphic. That isn’t a feature of the [D-Bus type system](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#type-system) by default (all argument lists must be concretely typed).

You can implement this yourself, though, using a single argument of type `a{sv}`, i.e. `MyMethod (a{sv} args)`. The D-Bus type `a{sv}` is a dictionary of string keys to variant values, and can contain zero or more such pairs. You can use it to allow a variable number of well-documented argument key/value pairs to be passed to your method.

You might want to read the [D-Bus API design guidelines](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-api-design.html) for more hints on how to design good D-Bus APIs.